# Wrong pagination Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I have 9 ADs in my website and i make the pagination with 10. Ok, the codeigniter make the pagination with 10 ads, but in the second and last page it should show only 3 ADs, show 10 (7 the other page and the 3 that should be alone).

This is my code:

(Controller)

```
class Classificados extends MY_Controller {
    public function index($offset = 0) {

      // load pagination library 

        $this->load->library('pagination'); 
        $limit = 6;
        $config = array();
        $config['base_url']             = base_url('');
        $config['uri_segment']          = 1;
        $config['total_rows']           = $this->classificados_model->somarTodos($f_estado, $f_cidade); 
        $config['per_page']             = $limit;
        $config['use_page_numbers']     = TRUE;
        $config['num_links']            = 2;
        $config['first_link']           = 'Primeiro';
        $config['last_link']            = 'Último';
        $config['next_link']            = '&raquo;';
        $config['prev_link']            = '&laquo;';
        $config['first_tag_open']       = '<li>';
        $config['first_tag_close']      = '</li>';
        $config['last_tag_open']        = '<li>';
        $config['last_tag_close']       = '</li>';
        $config['prev_tag_open']        = '<li>';
        $config['prev_tag_close']       = '</li>';
        $config['next_tag_open']        = '<li>';
        $config['next_tag_close']       = '</li>';
        $config['cur_tag_open']         = '<li class="active"><a href="javascript:">';
        $config['cur_tag_close']        = ' <span class="sr-only">(current)</span> </a></li>';
        $config['full_tag_open']        = '<nav>
                <ul class="pagination">';
            $config['full_tag_close']   = '</ul>
        </nav>';
        $config['num_tag_open']         = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close']        = '</li>';      
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $dados['anuncios']          =   $this->classificados_model->buscaAnuncios($limit, $offset, $f_estado, $f_cidade);
        $dados['paginacao']         =   $this->pagination->create_links();
```

(Model)

Classificados_Model

```
function buscaAnuncios($limit, $offset, $f_estado, $f_cidade) {
        $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
        $where = array(
            'estados.sigla'                 =>  $f_estado, 
            'cidades.nome'                  =>  $f_cidade,
            'anuncios.anuncio_ativo'        =>  '1',
            'usuarios.bloqueado_usuario'    =>  '0',
            'usuarios.ativado_usuario'      =>  '1'
        );

        $this
            ->db
            ->select("*")
            ->from("usuarios")
            ->join("anuncios", "anuncios.usuario_anuncio_id = usuarios.id_usuario", "inner")
            ->join("estados", "estados.id = usuarios.estado_usuario", "inner")
            ->join("cidades", "cidades.id = usuarios.cidade_usuario AND estados.id = cidades.id_uf", "inner")


            ->order_by("anuncios.data_anuncio","desc");

            $query = $this->db->get_where('', $where);


        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

Procedure for page 2:

```
SELECT *
FROM (`usuarios`)
INNER JOIN `anuncios` ON `anuncios`.`usuario_anuncio_id` = `usuarios`.`id_usuario`
INNER JOIN `estados` ON `estados`.`id` = `usuarios`.`estado_usuario`
INNER JOIN `cidades` ON `cidades`.`id` = `usuarios`.`cidade_usuario` AND estados.id = cidades.id_uf
WHERE `estados`.`sigla` =  'rj'
AND `cidades`.`nome` =  'rio de janeiro'
AND `anuncios`.`anuncio_ativo` =  '1'
AND `usuarios`.`bloqueado_usuario` =  '0'
AND `usuarios`.`ativado_usuario` =  '1'
ORDER BY `anuncios`.`data_anuncio` desc
LIMIT 2, 10
```

My route.php:

```
$route['(:num)']                    = "classificados/index/$1";
```

Ps: Now i have 19 ADs and change limit to 6, only for this pagination test.

Thanks advanced!

Comment: pagination makes the page links but displaying content on that page depends on you.what you did at your view?Provided code does not related with your question.

Comment: My problem is in paging, not the content.
Unfortunately on the second page is also showing some of the first page content, when it should only show the relevant content to the second page.

Prints:
Page 1:
http://prntscr.com/6n4t5x
http://prntscr.com/6n4sra
Page 2:
http://prntscr.com/6n4tat
http://prntscr.com/6n4tg4

Ps: Now i have 15 ADs

Comment: You should show us your db query and what limit/offset you use in your query to be able to give you an answer.

Comment: I will edit my post! 
Sorry...

Comment: @ShaifulIslam.. u can help with this question?

Comment: @sotoz... u can help with this question?

Comment: I did not asked for your page contents I just asked for the link of pages.How ever I will provide a solution.

Comment: Sorry @ShaifulIslam, my English is very bad. If I understand, you want the site link for you to see in person? This is a site: http://rj.rio-de-janeiro.tudoparasuafesta.com.br

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you used `$config['base_url']= base_url('');`.which will produce link like this

```
 baseurl/1   it means 1 is controller name
 baseurl/2   means 2 is controller name.
 In that case you need to use router function.
```

Alternatively you can use this.This will solve your problem

```
$config['base_url']             = base_url().'YOUR_CONTROLLER/index';    
$config['uri_segment']          = 3;
```

**UPDATE**
  You said your router contains this code

```
$route['(:num)'] = "classificados/index/$1";
```

In that case your All code is ok except the model limit query.
At your model's `buscaAnuncios` function

```
$this->db->limit($limit, $offset);//this line is wrong
```

actually `$offset` contains the page number so you are not getting actual offset.

Replace that line with those codes

```
 $offset--;
 if($offset<0)
 {
     $offset=0;
 }
 $this->db->limit($limit, $offset*$limit);
```

Hope this codes will solve your problem

Comment: Don't work too.. shows the same thing but with different link.

Comment: what is your controller name? and what is your base url?

Comment: The controller is "classificados"

Comment: so do you get page link for `rj.rio-de-janeiro.tudoparasuafesta.com.br/classificados/2` for page 2?or `rj.rio-de-janeiro.tudoparasuafesta.com.br/classificados/index/2`

Comment: rj.rio-de-janeiro.tudoparasuafesta.com.br/classificados/2

Comment: Now i have 19 ADs in this city.

Comment: Sorry! My route.php:
$route['(:num)']     = "classificados/index/$1";

Comment: Please update your question with edited code.Your classificados controller's index function and relative model.Its hard to figure